# Javascript replace all in substring with special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace ALL occurrences of '|B' with ''  I've tried using 'replace' which only replaces the first occurrence in a string, and both of the following ReplaceAll prototypes neither of which produce the desired result:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.replace(new RegExp(search, 'g'), replacement);
};
```

and

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show strings you tested?

Comment: The pipe has special meaning in the RegEx, that should be escaped by preceding a backslash `\|B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a RegExp from an expression, you could have characters that need to be escaped so they are not treated as RegExp. In your case, the `|` is a special character in regular expressions.

See [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript)

```
// Shamelessly copy/pasted from the link above
RegExp.escape = function(s) {
    return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    return this.replace(new RegExp(RegExp.escape(search), 'g'), replacement);
};
```

Comment: Thanks!  This worked perfectly!